# Turn off scrollwheel clicks

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

My IDE does some weird things when I click/tap the scrollwheel. I still want to be able to use the scrollwheel for scrolling but I want to turn off the scrollwheel for tapping/clicking. How can I do that?

The mouse make/model is Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 3500.

I don't see that option here :(

[image]

The output of **synclient**, is:

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 49
    RightEdge               = 1179
    TopEdge                 = 50
    BottomEdge              = 878
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 67
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 30
    HorizScrollDelta        = 30
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.129955
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 7
    VertHysteresis          = 7
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 614
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 760
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: i fixed it, sorry it was confusing

Comment: No worries: what's the output of `synclient`? Please [edit] your question to provide that info there.

Comment: Hmmm...  Can you try `synclient Clickpad=0` and see what that does?

Comment: @Fabby will that modify the file? How would I change it back?

Comment: @Fabby  changing Clickpad to 0 seems to negatively impact my trackpad unfortunately. Just to be clear, I am not trying to change the settings of my trackpad, I am trying to change my mouse so that the scrollwheel is not clickable.

Comment: I think it's called the "middle" click, as opposed to left/right click with the mouse. I want to turn off middle click.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Not really following this but Left Click is "1", Middle Click is "2" and Right Click is "3" in most configuration files / apps. Also you don't mention the type of mouse you have, nor the settings defined for it. Something like xinput list. Haven't experimented with my Logitech Pro MX mouse yet even though it has something like 12 button combinations.

Comment: thanks for the info, I will add those details about the mouse model to the OP